# Get all numbers between pairs of numbers, which are in an array (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers

I have an array similar to following:

```
[38, 40, 51, 53, 57, 59, 70, 72, 104, 106, 111, 113, 117, 130, 134, 148, 154, 156]
```

All odd indexes in this array are start numbers and all even indexes are stop numbers. From this array I want to create another array which well contain all these numbers in this array plus other numbers in between. So the final output becomes:

```
[38, 39, 40, 51, 52, 53, 57, 58, 59, 70, 71, 72, 104, 105, 106, ... ]
```

Another example:
For input array `[5, 9, 12, 15, 21, 24, 30, 36]`
The output should be `[ 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 21, 22, 23, 24, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]`

Any help appreciated.

Here is what I am trying:

```
 for (var i=0;i<array1.length;i++) {
   if (i % 2 == 0) {
   var start = array1[i]; 
   var stop= array1[i+1]; 
   array2.push(start); 
   for (var j=start+1;j<=stop;start++){ 
     array2.push(j) 
   } 
  } 
 }
```

I am getting the following error:
`FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

Comment: We understand that this is little tricky but where is your attempt ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: This is what I have: `for (var i=0;i<array1.length;i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0){
                var start = array1[i];
                var stop= array1[i+1];
                array2.push(start);
            
                for (var j=start+1;j<=stop;start++){
                    array2.push(j)
                } 
            }
        }`

Comment: I have updated the question to include sample code and error. PTAL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an infinite loop, because you do not increment `j`, but `start`, which have no influence for `j`.

```
for (var j = start + 1; j <= stop; start++) { 
//                                 ^^^^^^^
```

needs to be

```
for (var j = start + 1; j <= stop; j++) { 
//                                 ^^^
```

---

A bit more concise version could be this approach:

While you have always pairs of numbers, you could iterate the array and increment the index by `2`, because the two values are needed in the loop for using the value at index for a start value and the value at `index + 1` as end value.

Inside of the `for` loop, you could take a temporary variable `value` for incrementing and pushing to the result set.

Then you need a `do ... while` statement, because first you need to push the actual (start) value to the result set and then increment that value and check against the end value of the array.

Proceed until no more items are in the array.

```js
var array = [38, 40, 51, 53, 57, 59, 70, 72, 104, 106, 111, 113, 117, 130, 134, 148, 154, 156],
    result = [],
    value,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i += 2) { // increment by 2
    value = array[i];                   // take start value
    do {
        result.push(value);             // push the value
        value++;                        // increase value
    } while (value <= array[i + 1])     // and check if the value is smaller or equal
}                                       // to the end value

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```